# PrimeNg DataTable click event

Tags: json, angular, datatable, primeng

I am doing attendance checking of student in app, so when I click on a table cell it adds me "X" into this cell and some value which I send with JSON that the cell is marked (student has an absence). I have implemented DataTable from PrimeNg because I think it is the best to use in my case, so question is how to implement this function? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you can use the editable cell feature of PrimeNG and place checkbox within it like this:

```
<p-column field="absence" header="Absence">
  <template let-col let-student="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
    <p-checkbox groupname="absence" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="student[col.field]" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
</template>
```

In this case of course you need an absence field in data that are placed in your table. As your field `absence` needs only true/false values you should set your checkbox (also PrimeNG component) binary attribute to true and bind it to your model.